# Empty array after calling the function that fills the array

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to get the array after it is filled in a function but it is empty when I print it out.

Code:

```
var usersList = [];
app.post('/submitLogin',function(req,res) {
    getUsersGroups();
    console.log(usersList);    
});

function getUsersGroups() {
    const users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConnection
        .getUsers()
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    });
    const groups = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConnection
        .getGroups()
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    });
    Promise.all([users, groups])
    .then(data => {
        usersList = data[0];
        groupsList = data[1];
        console.log(usersList)
    });
}
```

However, the console.log in the `getUsersGroups()`, prints out the filled array but it is empty in the `app.post('/submitLogin...')`

Why is this happening assuming that `getUsersGroups()` runs before I try to print out the array?

Comment: You are not returning anything.Return the promise and the that within.

Comment: I have tried to return it but it is ```undefined``` when I print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not observing the async execution of your db call.
The `console.log(usersList);` happens BEFORE the db call, so it is empty.

You must adapt your code like this and post the code AFTER the db execution:

```js
app.post('/submitLogin', function (req, res) {
  getUsersGroups().then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    res.send(data.usersList)
  })
})

function getUsersGroups () {
  const users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbConnection
      .getUsers()
      .then(data => {
        resolve(data)
      })
  })
  const groups = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbConnection
      .getGroups()
      .then(data => {
        resolve(data)
      })
  })
  return Promise.all([users, groups])
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data[0])
      return {
        usersList: data[0],
        groupsList: data[1]
      }
    })
}
```

I strongly suggest to don't change a global variable like `usersList` (that I removed from my example)
because if you receive two request contemporaneously, the second one could overwrite the data of the first one and
cause many side effect.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to try that, but a question... What if I need to access to the usersList variable in other functions? Will I have to call ```getUsersGroups()``` each time I need the data?

Comment: No, but if you are developing a statefull API you must be aware of that and avoid conflicts if thay can happen. For example if the user list is based on a "customerKey" you can create a `Map` with key: customerKey and value userList. So the HTTP request send the customerKay to access a dedicated userList

Comment: I understand. I am not developing an API but it is good to know. I have tried your code and it works now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.post('/submitLogin', async function(req,res) {
    await getUsersGroups();
    console.log(usersList);    
});
```

try this

Comment: Still empty array and my code editor says ```await has no effect on the type of this expression```